# Leibniz rule application

Tags: integration, partial-derivative

I want to compute the partial $\frac{\partial y(x)}{\partial x}$ using the following equality:

x=$\int^{y(x)}_0  a f(a,x) da$

How can I apply the Leibniz rule here?

Comment: What have you tried?  Did you use the formula for the [Leibniz rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)?

Answer (score 1):

Leibniz Rule give $1=y(x)f(y(x),x) y'(x)+\int_0^{y(x)} af_x(a,x)da$. Just solve for $y'(x)$ from this equation.